# Windows 10 messed up my boot (grub2)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 16.10, windows-10

I installed Windows 7 first then I installed Ubuntu 16.10. Dual boot was fine with Grub 2 as a boot-loader. Then I upgraded to Windows 10. I got a nice Windows boot-loader. However, I can't boot to Ubuntu. I used easyBCD to add Ubuntu to Windows boot loader but I still can't boot to Ubuntu.

I want to Keep Windows bootloader. How can I fix ubuntu?

Comment: Windows 10 has own dual boot window?

Comment: Yes, It does have.

Comment: @Gallifreyan All previous Windows versions had it.

Comment: @CelticWarrior  -  if Windows has dual boot, how does it muck up Ubuntu when installed last?

Comment: @Gallifreyan It always add its own bootloader that allowed for multibooting **other Windows**. EasyBCD is a "hack" that often doesn't work with UEFI.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows